# Fonts DPI problem in Firefox and Open Office

Tags: firefox, fonts, openoffice.org, dpi

I have changed fonts DPI from 96 to 85. Now the desktop really looks great but the problem is that Firefox and Open Office won't apply the new settings. They still use 96 DPI.

Any suggestion?

thx

Answer (score 1):

I just had to log out. Now everything look fine.